# Unwrapping breeze Entity properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, breeze

I'm very new to breeze/knockout, but I'm 99% of the way to doing what I need to do. I'm using the Hot Towel template, and I'm successfully retrieving a list of items via breeze. The entity (ITBAL) is a database first Entity Framework entity. When I look at the JSON coming back in Fiddler, I see the correct data. The problem is that all of the properties of data.results are dependentobservables, and not the raw values themselves.

We have a custom grid control that is trying to display the data.results array. Because it is not expecting observables, it is simply displaying "function dependentobservable" instead of the value.

I tried to unwrap the object, but keep getting the circular reference error. I don't know why that is, since ITBAL isn't associated with anything.

The data as Fiddler reports it:

```
[{"$id":"1","$type":"WebUIHtml5HotTowel.Models.ITBAL, WebUIHtml5HotTowel","IBITNO":"A100                       ","IBWHID":"1 ","IBITCL":"50","IBITSC":"3 ","IBSUSP":" ","IBVNNO":"100   ","IBPRLC":"        ","IBSCLC":"        ","IBCCCD":"P","IBPICD":" ","IBSAFL":"Y","IBSTCS":399.99000,"IBUSCS":0.00000,"IBAVCS":414.95214,"IBLCST":7.00000,"IBLCCC":20.0,"IBLCDT":110923.0,"IBLSCC":20.0,"IBLSDT":130111.0,"IBLXCC":19.0,"IBLXDT":990102.0,"IBMXO1":2100.000,"IBMXO2":0.000,"IBMXO3":0.000,"IBMNO1":5.000,"IBMNO2":0.000,"IBMNO3":0.000,"IBFOQ1":0.000,"IBFOQ2":0.000,"IBFOQ3":0.000,"IBOHQ1":327.000,"IBOHQ2":0.000,"IBOHQ3":0.000,"IBAQT1":1576.000,"IBAQT2":0.000,"IBAQT3":0.000,"IBBOQ1":50.000,"IBBOQ2":0.000,"IBBOQ3":0.000,"IBPOQ1":448.000,"IBPOQ2":0.000,"IBPOQ3":0.000,"IBIQT1":1446.000,"IBIQT2":0.000,"IBIQT3":0.000,"IBRMD1":10.000,"IBRMD2":0.000,"IBRMD3":0.000,"IBRYD1":10.000,"IBRYD2":0.000,"IBRYD3":0.000,"IBISM1":0.000,"IBISM2":0.000,"IBISM3":0.000,"IBISY1":0.000,"IBISY2":0.000,"IBISY3":0.000,"IBAMD1":0.000,"IBAMD2":0.000,"IBAMD3":0.000,"IBAYD1":0.000,"IBAYD2":0.000,"IBAYD3":0.000,"IBMMD1":0.000,"IBMMD2":0.000,"IBMMD3":0.000,"IBMYD1":0.000,"IBMYD2":0.000,"IBMYD3":0.000,"IBSMD1":1.0,"IBSMD2":0.0,"IBSMD3":0.0,"IBSYD1":1.0,"IBSYD2":0.0,"IBSYD3":0.0,"IBBLME":335.000,"IBBLYO":2680.000,"IBBLLY":1441.000,"IBNMTY":8.0,"IBNMLY":11.0,"IBQSMD":21.000,"IBQSYD":21.000,"IBQSLY":20.000,"IBISMD":16318.19,"IBISYD":16318.19,"IBISLY":45714.87,"IBCSMD":373.46,"IBCSYD":373.46,"IBCSLY":67.00,"IBDQMD":0.000,"IBDQYD":0.000,"IBDQLY":0.000,"IBDSMD":0.00,"IBDSYD":0.00,"IBDSLY":0.00,"IBDCMD":0.00,"IBDCYD":0.00,"IBDCLY":0.00,"IBNOMD":18.0,"IBNOYD":18.0,"IBNOLY":18.0,"IBPKMD":15.0,"IBPKYD":15.0,"IBPKLY":14.0,"IBINUS":"        ","IBIAID":0.0,"IBSAID":0.0,"IBCQT1":1527.000,"IBCQT2":0.000,"IBCQT3":0.000,"IBFCST":"Y","IBDRSH":" ","IBWMIU":"JP","IBFL15":"               ","IBUS20":"                    ","IBLPR1":0.00000,"IBLPR2":0.00000,"IBLPR3":0.00000,"IBLPR4":0.00000,"IBLPR5":0.00000,"IBLPCD":" ","IBABCC":"B","IBPRCL":0.0,"IBQBCL":"   ","IBACDC":"Y","IBTDCD":" ","IBDOUM":"   ","IBTP01":0.0,"IBTP02":0.0,"IBTP03":0.0,"IBTP04":0.0,"IBLMCC":20.0,"IBLMDT":130513.0,"IBTMPH":"Y","IBCOMC":" ","IBCOMF":0.00000,"IBITCT":"    ","IBEOQT":0.000,"IBITCM":0.0,"IBBRVW":" ","IBPTID":"  ","IBQTLT":0.0000,"IBCTY1":"AUS","IBCTY2":"AUS","IBTXCD":"1","IBREVS":"Y","IBITXC":"     ","IBMNOQ":0.000,"IBSTUS":0.000,"IBUS30":"                              ","IBPSLN":" ","IBPLIN":"N","IBUPDP":"Y","IBDFII":"2011-08-11T00:00:00.000","IBLHRK":"A","IBPLNC":"          "}]
```

My Controller:

```
    [BreezeController]
public class ItemInquiryController : ApiController
{

    readonly EFContextProvider<AplusEntities> _contextProvider = new EFContextProvider<AplusEntities>();

    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public string Metadata()
    {
        return _contextProvider.Metadata();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<ITBAL> ItemBalances(string itemNumber, string warehouse)
    {
        return _contextProvider.Context.ITBALs.Where(i => i.IBITNO == itemNumber && i.IBWHID == warehouse)
                               .OrderBy(i => i.IBWHID)
                               .ThenBy(i => i.IBITNO);


    }

}
```

The relevant portion from the viewmodel:

```
        var manager = new breeze.EntityManager("api/ItemInquiry");
    var store = manager.metadataStore;

    var itbalInitializer = function (itbal) {
        itbal.CompositeKey = ko.computed(function () {
            return itbal.IBITNO() + itbal.IBWHID();
        });
    };

    store.registerEntityTypeCtor("ITBAL", null, itbalInitializer);
    var index = "0" + (args.pageNum * args.pageSize);

    var query = new breeze.EntityQuery("ItemBalances")
        .withParameters({ itemNumber: "A100", warehouse: "1" })
        .take(args.pageSize);

    if (index > 0) {
        query = query.skip(index);
    }

    manager.executeQuery(query).then(function (data) {

        vm.itbals.removeAll();

        var itbals = data.results;//[0].Data;
        itbals.forEach(function (itbal) {
            vm.itbals.push(itbal);
        });

        vm.totalRecords(1);
        itemBalancesGrid.mergeData(vm.itbals(), args.pageNum, parseInt(vm.totalRecords()));

    }).fail(function (e) {
        logger.log(e, null, loggerSource, true, 'error');
    });
```

I figure I must be missing something fairly simple, but it is escaping me.

UPDATE: I removed the BreezeController attribute from the ApiController, and it works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jon, removing the `[Breeze]` attribute **effectively disables breeze** for your application so I don't think that is the long term answer to your problem.

If you don't actually want entities for this scenario - you just want data - than a Breeze projection that mentions just the data to display in the grid would seem to be the best choice. Projections return raw data that are not wrapped in KO observables and are not held in the Breeze `EntityManager` cache.

If you want the data *as cached entities* and you *also* want to display them in a grid that doesn't like KO observable properties ... read on.

You can unwrap a KO'd object with `ko.toJS`. However, the grid is likely to complain about circular references (or throw an "out of memory" exception as some grids do) ... even if the entity has no circular navigation paths. The difficulty stems from the fact that every Breeze entity has an inherent circularity by way of its `entityAspect` property:

```
  something.entityAspect.entity //'entity' points back to 'something'
```

Because you are using Knockout for your model library and because you say `ITBAL` has no navigation properties ("*is not related to anything*"), I think the following will work for you:

```
manager.executeQuery(query).then(success) ...

function success(data) {
    var unwrapped = ko.toJS(data.results).map(
                           function(entity) {
                              delete entity.entityAspect;
                              return entity;
                           });
    vm.itbals(unwrapped);
    vm.totalRecords(1); // huh? What is that "parseInt ..." stuff?
    itemBalancesGrid.mergeData(vm.itbals(), args.pageNum, parseInt(vm.totalRecords()));
})
```

`ko.toJS` is a Knockout function that recursively unwraps an object or collection of objects, returning copies of values. Then we iterate over the copied object graphs, deleting their `entityAspect` properties. The array of results is stuffed into the `vm.itbals` observable and handed along.

You can imagine how to generalize this to remove anything that is giving you trouble.

#### Extra

What the heck is `vm.totalRecords`?  I sense that this is supposed to be the total number of matching records before paging. You can get that from Breeze by adding `.inlineCount()` to the breeze query definition. You get the value after the query returns from the `data.inlineCount` property.

Do you really need `vm.itbals()`? If all you do here is pass values to the grid, why not do that and cut out the middle man?

The following success callback combines these thoughts

```
function success(data) {
    var unwrapped = ko.toJS(data.results).map(
                           function(entity) {
                              delete entity.entityAspect;
                              return entity;
                           });
    itemBalancesGrid.mergeData(unwrapped, args.pageNum, data.inlineCount);
})
```

Comment: Thanks, Ward! I will give this a shot. Yes, TotalRecords was an attempt to get the same thing as inlineCount(). I tried inlineCount() before, and it kept returning as undefined. I am currently passing 1 to totalRecords until I can get that worked out.

Comment: Ward, that absolutely did the trick. Thanks! I'm still having a problem with inlineCount, but I suspect that's either a problem with my data provider (Progress DataDirect for DB2) or our database. The error is SQL0204N: *LIBL.BIGCOUNT in TABLE type * not found.